# Is it possible to access the DOM of a chrome extension (like the internal Chrome PDF viewer) through my own extension?

Tags: javascript, pdf, dom, google-chrome-extension, theory

Basically, I wanted to make a Chrome extension that bookmarks my PDF. Yeah, I know someone already made it (with the limited API #page), but I wanted to make my own to learn. I was thinking this was going to be easy: wanted to take the title, current page, first page canvas thumbnail, and save all that to local storage.

Then, I hit a roadblock. I was inspecting the html of the local pdf file, and it was just some embed tag, and that's it. After a day, I realized what I need is the html of the internal chrome pdf-viewer, which has the goods: title, page, and all. Well, I can't get it. Content scripts show me the DOM of the file, but I can't just make matches: chrome-extension://BLAHBLAH* and have instant access to Chrome's pdf viewer.

I'm not like a full-on developer and thought this would be a straightforward hobby project, but now it's not looking good. So theoreotically, what will it take. Do I have to modify chrome's internal extension, putting in some background communication script to pass messages with my extension? What about Adobe's PDF reader? Would that be easier to accomplish with this method if it's even possible in the first place?

I don't want to just give up because it's not convenient. I may learn a lot more if I keep going.

Well, there wasn't much to try. The forums talking about internal PDF viewers were like 5 years old and didn't really bring much hope. Like even looking at my own question, obviously duh not possible because "security concerns". However, what about a "hacky" make it work way? I want to believe I can make a simple bookmark extension lol.

---

Update: Ok, I was able to find an open-source pdf viewer on GitHub that functions as a Chrome extension (like Adobe Acrobat PDF). I now see in the files for the extension, I have full access to the HTML for the pdf viewer. I'm guessing during runtime, I will be able to feed information from the pdf extension to my own through API. Finally making progress. Nice.

---

[Oh yeahh....](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6WtC.png)

Comment: Well, the only thing I really needed from the pdf viewer was the title of the document, the current page, and the canvas of the first page (to get image). I ended up using some open source pdf viewer on GitHub and added it as an extension. From there I had access to viewer.js, which I used to pass document information to the service worker, which sent the information to my extension. I mean idk if this the right approach, but it works in the end at least.

Comment: "generally have no HTML counterpart" --> ok but if you go to Edge and inspect element on a PDF file. There's an HTML file for pdf UI. It's like edge/extensions/index.html like you said. But I had no luck getting that information out and into my Chrome extension.

Comment: Yeah, I had no clue PDFs were going to be this complex and restrictive, but I'm glad I was able to succeed (even though it was messy solution).